# How to plot multiple glmer models into one single plot?

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot

I have two `glmer` models with two covariates each that I'm trying to plot into a single figure.

**MWE**:

```
## generalized linear mixed model
library(lattice)

cbpp$response <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=nrow(cbpp))
gm1 <- glmer(response ~ size + incidence + (1 | herd),
              data = cbpp, family = binomial)

cbpp$obs <- 1:nrow(cbpp)
gm2 <- glmer(response ~ size + incidence + (1 | herd) +  (1|obs),
              family = binomial, data = cbpp)
```

I am trying to plot the predicted values againts each covariate for each model. I found the `sjPlot` library and the [`plot_model`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.6.2/topics/plot_model) function, which can plot these predictions when using `type = "pred"`. Calling this function individually on each model works perfect and yields two separate figures like this for each model:

[image]

However I'm not familiar with R and I am having a hard time trying to plot the 4 plots on the same figure.

The `plot_model` function has a `grid` parameter, which only works for models with a Poisson distirbution. For `gm1` and `gm2`, I am getting the following error when I call `plot_model(gm1, type = "pred", grid = TRUE)`:

```
Error in if (attr(x, "logistic", exact = TRUE) == "1" && attr(x, "is.trial",  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Anyway, I would not be able to plot the three models in one figure using this so I tried three different approaches. First, I saw the [`plot_models`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjPlot/versions/2.6.2/topics/plot_models) function, which takes multiple models as input. When I try to pass the two models as arguments, calling `plot_models(gm1, gm2)` I get the following error:

```
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Second, I tried using the `par` function setting the `mfrow` and then calling `plot_model` again without success. I don't get any error but the plots keep showing as individual figures.

Third, I tried using the `gridExtra` library. Calling

```
p1 <- plot_model(gm1, type = "pred")
p2 <- plot_model(gm2, type = "pred")
grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

results in the following error:

```
Error in gList(list(ppt = list(data = list(x = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Does anyone have an insight on this?

**EDIT**

Comment: Please edit your post to include reproducible sample data and code to provide us with something to work. It's very difficult (i.e. impossible) to help with questions of the form "I'm getting error XYZ" without knowing anything about the data that caused the error(s). I recommend taking a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
pp1 <- plot_model(gm1,type="pred")
pp2 <- plot_model(gm2,type="pred")
plot_grid(c(pp1,pp2))
```

Comment: Just a comment here, syntax that worked for me is "plot_grid(list(pp1,pp2))"