# How to plot two glms in one plot with double axis?

Tags: r, plot, glm, sjplot

Imagine that I have the sample data below:

```
RespVar1 <- runif(n=18, min=55, max=120)
RespVar2 <- runif(n=18, min=0.3, max=0.5)
PredVar <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(RespVar1, RespVar2, PredVar)
```

Where I run these models:

```
M1 <- glm(RespVar1 ~ PredVar, data=df, family=gaussian())
M2 <- glm(RespVar2 ~ PredVar, data=df, family=gaussian())
```

My question is: How can I plot the two model plots below (including the data and the model line) in a double-axis plot in R? (for instance, RespVar1 on the left axis, RespVar2 on the right axis, and PredVar on the x axis)

```
library(sjPlot)    
plot_model(M1, type="pred", terms="PredVar", show.data=T)
plot_model(M2, type="pred", terms="PredVar", show.data=T)
```

Thanks!

Comment: look here to start? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978360/how-to-plot-multiple-glmer-models-into-one-single-plot

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @CAWA. However, this solution doesn´t include both models in the same plotting region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technically does want you want, you will have adjust how you plot your lines so that the axes make more sense. But in essence this is it. You could replace the lines() calls for the CI's with polygon() calls and a col=c() setting that matches your needs. You will also probably need to adjust the label values for the second y axis to your specific needs.

FWIW, a much wiser person than me said: "if you need 2 Y axes, you're doing it wrong"

Your data

```
RespVar1 <- runif(n=18, min=55, max=120)
RespVar2 <- runif(n=18, min=0.3, max=0.5)
PredVar <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(RespVar1, RespVar2, PredVar)
```

The models

```
M1 <- glm(RespVar1 ~ PredVar, data=df, family=gaussian())
M2 <- glm(RespVar2 ~ PredVar, data=df, family=gaussian())
```

'New data' for predictions, a lazy way to do this.

```
new.data<-data.frame(PredVar=PredVar)
```

Predictions

```
pred1<-predict(M1, newdata = new.data, se=TRUE)
pred2<-predict(M2, newdata = new.data, se=TRUE)
```

Confidence intervals for plotting

```
ci_lwr1 <- with(pred1, fit + qnorm(0.025)*se.fit)
ci_upr1 <- with(pred1, fit + qnorm(0.975)*se.fit)

ci_lwr2 <- with(pred2, fit + qnorm(0.025)*se.fit)
ci_upr2 <- with(pred2, fit + qnorm(0.975)*se.fit)
```

The plot:

```
plot(pred1$fit~new.data$PredVar, type="l", ylim=c(0,120), col='red')
lines(ci_lwr1~new.data$PredVar, col="red")
lines(ci_upr1~new.data$PredVar, col="red")

lines(pred2$fit~new.data$PredVar, col="blue")
lines(ci_lwr2~new.data$PredVar, col="blue") # CIs are hard to see
lines(ci_upr2~new.data$PredVar, col="blue") # CIs are hard to see

points(RespVar1~PredVar, data=df)
points(RespVar2~PredVar, data=df)
axis(4, at=c(0,20,40,60,80, 100, 120), labels=round(seq(0,1,length=7),2))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! this worked very well! The only thing I don´t understand is why do you suggest to use the polygon function - although I think this is not a stack overflow question. Thanks for your help @CAWA!

Comment: @Teresa I only suggest that because the original code you presented displayed the confidence intervals as polygons and not lines. The polygon function is easy enough to figure out but it does require entering quite a few lines of code...which is mostly why I didn't do it here.